# Scrapy getting redirected

Tags: python, web, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to take data from this [amazon page](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_13896615011_2529580011_ln?srs=2529580011&rh=n%3A13896615011&ie=UTF8&qid=1464956176&scn=13896615011&h=4f68f64151566295c00f8b63baa57f9aa1cdeb07) however I am always getting sent back to the main page for [HP](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?srs=2529580011). I've tried suggestions I've seen from other posts about changing my USER_AGENT and that has not helped in this case. Additionally, because cookies are enabled in scrapy by default I have even tried getting to the page I want through other pages first and that has not worked.

Here is my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    url_to_go = "http://amazon.com"+(response.xpath('//*[@id="refinements"]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/@href').extract()[0])

    cook = {'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate', 
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie':'session-token="lslMFQ/aZv4uOPOndfqyl4uQo+2j28Ziy3aMBwCCUsVPeFX9xoCsUv6jvR2U+YAnSxlBVTl4PtTpCeaIA13g2/XC1DqNd95tDulSOPeEbxETVBgwS4i/vTIQmUOybv+I5wYP12XCIGOh7QrpGLE+/gGTgAjM+1KaA9Ua6D2lEZoPPyONk8K4MiWAOxbjOVgaV/i5lbEbp1Kfn4PbXl555g=="; x-wl-uid=1ZDt5hegLdX+sR4SzNbD6q5TZD/tTVmo+y68B5HuediDPf5/oClQ5IbnNGcF0D+ollnxQ1vp63iw=; csm-hit=s-0AMVHWRT97Q8WVYKN4TA|1464956175963; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=186-8139005-7450816; ubid-main=181-6639382-1676153',
    'Host':'www.amazon.com',
    'Origin':'http://www.amazon.com',
    'Referer':'http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_13896615011_2529580011_ln/184-2672682-0617523?srs=2529580011&rh=n%3A13896615011&ie=UTF8&qid=1464897830&scn=13896615011&h=d5e0fad5fcbb448fb4f65192f8ecdc6f0425487e'}



    request = Request(url_to_go, headers = cook, meta={'asinlist':[]}, callback=self.scrape)
    return request
```

The request I return is a request for the page that I actually want to scrape. Does anyone know a way I can be able to scrape something from this webpage?

```
Response as requested:
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2016-06-03 08:50:09 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2016-06-03 08:50:09 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddl
eware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
eadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-06-03 08:50:09 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddlewa
re, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-06-03 08:50:09 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: LinkcrawlerPipeline
2016-06-03 08:50:09 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-06-03 08:50:09 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2016-06-03 08:50:09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-06-03 08:50:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.amazon.com/s/r
ef=sr_nr_n_0?srs=2529580011> (referer: None)
2016-06-03 08:50:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://amazon.com/s/ref=s
r_nr_scat_13896615011_2529580011_ln/182-9928517-8357940?srs=2529580011&rh=n%3A13
896615011&ie=UTF8&qid=1464958209&scn=13896615011&h=0821a5f910d5cd8152cac30d0456f
e79538da1fb> (referer: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_13896615011_252958
0011_ln/184-2672682-0617523?srs=2529580011&rh=n%3A13896615011&ie=UTF8&qid=146489
7830&scn=13896615011&h=d5e0fad5fcbb448fb4f65192f8ecdc6f0425487e)
2016-06-03 08:50:11 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://amazon.c
om/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_13896615011_2529580011_ln/182-9928517-8357940?srs=2529580011
&rh=n%3A13896615011&ie=UTF8&qid=1464958209&scn=13896615011&h=0821a5f910d5cd8152c
ac30d0456fe79538da1fb> (referer: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_13896615
011_2529580011_ln/184-2672682-0617523?srs=2529580011&rh=n%3A13896615011&ie=UTF8&
qid=1464897830&scn=13896615011&h=d5e0fad5fcbb448fb4f65192f8ecdc6f0425487e)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\twist
ed\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\usr\Desktop\linkcrawler\linkcrawler\spiders\crawl.py", line 6
5, in scrape
    item_list = response.xpath('//*[contains(@id=,"result_"]').extract()
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrap
y\http\response\text.py", line 109, in xpath
    return self.selector.xpath(query)
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrap
y\selector\unified.py", line 100, in xpath
    raise ValueError(msg if six.PY3 else msg.encode("unicode_escape"))
ValueError: Invalid XPath: //*[contains(@id=,"result_"]
2016-06-03 08:50:11 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-06-03 08:50:11 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1199,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 147875,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 12, 50, 11, 340000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/ERROR': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 3, 12, 50, 9, 310000)}
2016-06-03 08:50:11 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

If you try to access the page I want to scrape in shell with the command

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="whatever" http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_13896615011_2529580011_ln?srs=2529580011&rh=n%3A13896615011&ie=UTF8&qid=1464956176&scn=13896615011&h=4f68f64151566295c00f8b63baa57f9aa1cdeb07
```

and you try view(response) you will see that the page that scrapy sees is not the page that was in the URL.

Comment: `yield` the request instead of `return`

Comment: Tried it, didn't make a difference. This parse function just starts my actual function for parsing the webpage. I tried this as a sketchy fix to my issue but it did not fix it. The issue is: when the request is being fulfilled with the url_to_go (which is the actual page I want to scrape), the webpage redirects me back to the start.

Comment: can you edit your question with the scrapy output (in the command line) when that happens?

Comment: Edited. This xpath is correct I'm pretty sure. The issue is it's not reaching that page because it gets redirected and then the xpath will fail. Also included example of replication through scrapy shell.

Comment: the error tells you what's wrong `response.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"result_"]').extract()` You have an additional `=` that is creating that error

Comment: @Rafael I have tried removing it too. Additionally, in my parse function I have 'code' (response.xpath('//*[@id="refinements"]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a/@href').extract()[0]) which does not throw an error. The error is with the response page not being the page that I want.

Comment: then the error you updated your question doesn't help me at all because the error I see has nothing to do with redirections. Also, the http redirect code is 302 if you see that instead of 200 then you know that you are being redirected

Comment: Hmmm. If you try to visit the url that it goes to: [link] (http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_scat_13896615011_2529580011_ln/189-9002580-1953520?srs=2529580011&rh=n%3A13896615011&ie=UTF8&qid=1464961168&scn=13896615011&h=48ab2dac75436582a6588ab3800db899292c4e75) and you try to go to do it in scrapy shell, it will give you a different page. If I post my complete code would it help? I'm almost completely sure my xpath is correct.

Comment: go ahead and post the complete code so I can test on my machine